# How to re-evaluate c++ function bound to qml property on dependent property change?

Tags: c++, qt, binding, qml, signals-slots

I want to bind a method of a C++ class to a QML component property and re-evaluate it when a dependent property changes. The following QML component does what I want:

```
// Converter.qml:
import QtQuick 2.0

QtObject {
    property double rate: 1
    function exchange(amount) { return amount * rate }
}
```

If I assign the result of the `exchange` function to a property like so,

```
Text { text: converter.exchange(100) }
```

the Text element will automatically update when `rate` is changed.  This works with a QML component, but I do not know how to do it with a C++ class.

I would like to implement a functionally equivalent class in C++:

```
#include <QObject>

class Convert : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(double rate READ rate WRITE setRate NOTIFY rateChanged)

public:
    explicit Convert(QObject *parent = 0)
        : QObject(parent), m_rate(1.0)
    { }

signals:
    void rateChanged();

public slots:
    double exchange(double amount) { return m_rate * amount; }

    double rate() { return m_rate; }

    void setRate(double r) {
        m_rate = r;
        emit rateChanged();
    }

private:
    double m_rate;
};
```

The `rate` property is accessible from QML, but changing it does not signal to the QML engine that 'exchange' should be re-evaluated.

Here is my main.qml:

```
// main.qml
import QtQuick 2.1
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1
import Utils 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    width: 300; height: 200
    visible: true

//    Converter { id: converter; rate: rateField.text }
    CppConverter { id: converter; rate: rateField.text }
    Column {
        TextField { id: rateInput; text: '0.41' }
        TextField { id: amountInput; text: '100.00' }
        Text { id: output; text: converter.exchange(amountField.text).toFixed(2) }
    }
}
```

If I enable the `CppConverter`, the output is updated when I change the `amountInput`, **but** not when I change the `rateInput`.  If I comment-in the QML Converter element, the update works fine.

With the QML Converter, the QML runtime identifies the dependency on the rate property and re-evaluates the exchange function when the rate is changed.  How can I indicate to the QmlEngine to do the same in the C++ version?

Comment: What's about a *exchangeChanged* signal and every time it is emitted, reasign its value to text property. It's not as clean as property binding mechanism but it should work. I'm surprised with this behavior. I have never though that samething like *function-result-changed* signal exists in QML. I could have a small idea why this works, but I hope that someone else can explain it.

Comment: It makes sense that the QML runtime can figure it out since [bindings can be of arbitrary complexity](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/propertybinding.html). It's just pushing the binding behind a function call. If only it were so simple in C++... that's 5X more lines of code to only do half the job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way to do this currently.

I don't think relying on a function being re-evaluated like this is a good practice, though. You should either explicitly call it when necessary:

```
Connections {
    target: converter
    onRateChanged: output.text = converter.exchange(amountField.text)
}
```

Or convert exchange() into a property, and approach it declaratively instead of imperatively (code not complete or tested):

```
class Convert : public QObject
{
    // ...
    Q_PROPERTY(double amount READ amount WRITE setAmount NOTIFY amountChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(double exchange READ exchange NOTIFY exchangeChanged)

    // ...

public:
    double exchange() { return m_rate * m_amount; }

private:
    double m_rate;
    double m_amount;
};
```

You'd then need to emit the various *Changed signals, etc. in the appropriate places.

Comment: I want to use C++ for performance and plan to implicitly use the rate value in hundreds of bindings. Adding onRateChanged is too much syntax for the scale but I'm mulling over the exchange property versus giving up and just using the QML Converter pattern.

Comment: There was no way to do it what I wanted, and you were correct; what I wanted was not a Qt solution. I ended up doing exactly what you said, exposing a property and emitting the change signal when the dependent values change. The implementation was extremely simple.